# Traktor audio 6 recognizes only one deck when pluging into my mac pro, what should i do?

Tags: software, dj, traktor

Last weekend i used my traktor audio 6 interface as usually and it was working fine. Yesterday, when i attemped to use it again, it only show me the enable botton at one deck(As you may know this interface when connecting into the usb port have to be activated by enabling each deck to work with), the other remained as any interface was plugged in.

What should i do in this case? does anyone knows how to fix this kind of issue?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I can't post this as a comment yet, so it'll have to be an answer. Usually this happens when the audio signal is screwed up somehow coming from the table. Set Traktor to scope view and see what the signal looks like. Check the settings in the audio 6 control panel- is direct monitoring on? Are the line input sensitivities set properly? Did you try rebooting the Macbook and/or plugging the audio 6 in on a different USB? Are you using an external power supply, or are you powering over the USB? Are you using timecode vinyl? Are your needles clean/connected properly? Are your grounds connected? Do you have the deck set to CD/LINE rather than to TURNTABLE/PHONO? There are many things it could be; a better description of what it is doing might help. :)
Hope this helps.